# Resize WebView for ipad swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3, uiwebview

I have a First View, where when I click on one button, it opens an UIWebView,

I want this webView to take only 3/4 of my view when I look at it from an Ipad, if it's an Iphone I want to get a full screen view.

Here is my code :

```
override func loadView() {

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

I try the method init with arbitrary values `frame: .init(x: 20, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20)`

But it's still taking full screen, for detect if it's an Ipad I use this condition

```
if (UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom.rawValue == 1)
    {
        // if here I'm an Ipad I can resize my webview
        webView.frame.size.height = view.frame.height - // some number
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this exactly what adaptive user interfaces and size classes in Interface Builder is for? Have a look at [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/216/) from 2014.

Comment: I'm not sure is work in my case, I  do everything with code

Comment: ...and now you see why that can be a gigantic waste of your time and effort. This problem becomes trivial when you use the tools Apple gives you, which were specifically designed to simplify this complex, multivariate design problem. A few clicks would give you exactly the differentiation you needed for the iPad case without writing a single line of code. "Work smarter, not harder" is extremely applicable here. :-)